# How to add text outputted into my table to one array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add some text to an array that's dynamically outputted by my database. However, with the way my function is set up currently, it adds each value to it's own separate array. I need them to be pushed to the same array because I need to get the sum of all the numbers that are outputted.

This is my function to convert the text to a number and then push them to an array.

```
$(".sumCosts").each(function(){
            let valuesArray = [];
            let values = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''));
            valuesArray.push(values);
            console.log(valuesArray);
        })
```

This is the HTML output. I'm interested in the `<td>` with class sumCosts, marked with *.

```
<table class="table text-light">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        <th class="text-start" scope="col">Implementation or Annual</th>
                                        <th class="text-start" scope="col">Category</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Cost ($)</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Hours</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="text-end">
                                        <td class="text-start">implementation</td>
                                        <td class="text-start">emo</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts">4,091</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end">85</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/1">
                                                <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/1">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                    <tbody><tr class="text-end">
                                        <td class="text-start">implementation</td>
                                        <td class="text-start">analysts</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts">6,282</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end">130.5</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/2">
                                                <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/2">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                    <tbody><tr class="text-end">
                                        <td class="text-start">implementation</td>
                                        <td class="text-start">maintenance</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts">2,873</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end">72.5</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/3">
                                                <button id="3" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/3">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                    <tbody><tr class="text-end">
                                        <td class="text-start">implementation</td>
                                        <td class="text-start">materials</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts">1,185</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/4">
                                                <button id="4" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/4">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                    <tbody><tr class="text-end">
                                        <td class="text-start">annual</td>
                                        <td class="text-start">emo</td>
                                        ***<td class="text-end sumCosts">313</td>***
                                        <td class="text-end"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="/find/costs_hours/5">
                                                <button id="5" type="button" class="btn btn-warning getId"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="deleteId" href="/delete/costs_hours/5">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

This is what is logged to the console

```
[4091]
[6282]
[2873]
[1185]
[313]
```

I need to be able to put them into the same array so that I can get a sum of all the numbers. Any advice on how to achieve this is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Define `valuesArray` _outside_ the `each` callback

Comment: i think you should put the "let valuesArray = [];" outside the $.each

Comment: Or use `map()` to define the array's value upon declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had to just move valuesArray Outside the function nothing more !

Using vanilla js

**JS**

```
  let ele = document.querySelectorAll(".sumCosts")
  let ar = Array.from(ele)

  let valuesArray = [];
  ar.forEach(ele => {
    let values = parseInt(ele.innerText.replace(/,/g, ''));
    valuesArray.push(values);
  })
  console.log(valuesArray);
```

**jQuery**

```
  let valuesArray = [];
  $(".sumCosts").each(function() {
    let values = parseInt($(this).text().replace(/,/g, ''));
    valuesArray.push(values);
  })
  console.log(valuesArray);
```